# Question making

Tags: questions, passive-voice

"**Have the potatoes been fried**?" OR  "**have the potatoes got fried ?**" 
Do these questions  sound natural or awkward?if natural,which one is more appropriate?

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Proofreading requests are out of scope.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of the two: -

> Have the potatoes been fried?

Sounds more natural. In this particular construction however, as fried is already past tense the sentence is a little clumsy with fried juxtaposted alongside been.

> Are the potoes fried?

Reads better.

Comment: Thank you gary . I have another doubt now. If i want to ask a person who is frying the potatoes ,and i am not sure if has done with frying or not  then which would suit more a)are the  potatoes fried ? B) have the potatoes been fried?

Comment: You are very welcome. In this case the potatoes could be part fried, so to avoid ambiguity I would say "Have you finished frying the potatoes?".